# CSS - Refer to a completely other element in the dom structure instead of a child or sibling in 2023

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know that CSS language changed a few in the last 10 years https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php, wondering if now 2023, there's a possibility to change a property in a completely other location instead of the childrens or siblings inside a dom structure.

Example

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div>other stuff</div>
<div>
    <some various nesting>
        <div id="c"></div>
    </some various nesting>
</div>
```

Let's say I need to change #a from #c in this way

```
#c:hover #a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

This would not work because #a ins't inside #c, there's a way to do it in pure css without having to use necessarly jquery or plain js? I would like to use a selector like if it was #c:hover getElementById("a") {
...
}

I tried also:

```
#c:hover :root #a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

with no success.

That would be very helpful finish stylizing lot of stuff that normally relies on javascript but there are many times where users disable javascript for security reasons.

Comment: Nope. I suppose there might be a hacky method with some of the new selectors but it would be incredibly fragile. Javascript would be preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS pseudo-class [`has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

`#a:has(~ #c:hover)` means: hover on `#c` and `#c` follows `#a` (not directly)

Here's a demo:

```css
#a:has(~ #c:hover) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">other stuff</div>
<p>
<div id="b">div in the middle</div>
<p>
  <div id="c">various nesting</div>
```

Supported browsers: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work just in firefox, hoping they will support it soon.